# How do I get Google Photos to store full resolution photos after I changed the setting?

Tags: google-plus-photos

I started using Google Photos to backup all my photos in just standard resolution (their free version).  Now I just changed my setting in the auto-backup utility on my Mac to store them in the full resolution. I also changed another setting under Google+ settings to store full resolution images as well.  I also increased my Google Drive storage expecting this to rise dramatically.  But my storage usage didn't change much at all after I changed to full res images, and when I compare the dimensions from my iPhoto library to the same photo in Google Photos it doesn't match.  Google photos version has smaller dimensions.

Do I need to re-upload my whole library to Google Photos?  If so, how would I do that?  If not, then why isn't it updating my photos to their full resolution?

Answer (score 1):

I think Google will not re-upload your photo again. Because those photos already on Google Plus Photo. However Google will upload full resolution photos the moment you changed your settings. There is a little strange while Google+ count your storage limit.

> Google+ Photos: Only photos over 2048x2048 pixels and videos longer than 15 minutes count toward your storage limit.         ---[reference](https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/6558?hl=en)

So, the answer to your first question is Yes. You need to re-upload all your photos to Google+ Photos. You can use **Picasa** to re-upload your photos.